# Given a known line segment and two known horizontal lines, how do I find the line subsegment between the two parallels?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to clip a line segment between two parallel horizontal lines.

I know the location of the two vertices on the larger segment, but need to know the points at which it intersects the horizontal lines.

[image]

What is the best way to calculate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation of the diagonal line is $y-y_1=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}(x-x_1)$, i.e. $y=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}(x-x_1)+y_1$ So, the $x$ coordinate of the upper point satisfies
$$75=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}(x-x_1)+y_1$$
and the $x$ coordinate of the lower point satisfies
$$25=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}(x-x_1)+y_1.$$

Now you can solve these for $x$.

Comment: Sorry, the image doesn't quite express the situation accurately. I used (200,200) as an example. In reality, the larger segment's coordinates will be quite different.

Comment: @Brennan: Ah, I see. So, we know two points $(a,b),(c,d)$ and two horizontal lines $y=e,y=f$, don't we? In that case, find the equation of the diagonal line $y-b=\frac{b-d}{a-c}(x-a)$, then set $y=e$ and $y=f$ to get the $x$ coordinates of the intersection points.

Comment: Excellently easy, thanks!

Comment: @Brennan: I edited my answer. I hope it helps.